# PHP - Somar tudo e dar um valor

Tags: php

Boas,

Criei este scriptzinho para verificar da DB, somar todos os records com aquele ID e depois dar um alert com a soma total.

Mas... não esta a dar, apenas mostra 1 record.

```
 $exp_selector = "SELECT reward_qty FROM public_rewards WHERE client_id = '".$_SESSION['u_id']."'";     
 $exp_query = $con->query($exp_selector);

 $reward_exp = rand(10,25);        

  while($exp_detail = $exp_query->fetch_array()) {

        $percentages = $exp_detail['reward_qty'];
        $sum_value += $percentages;         

        echo "<script>alert('$sum_value');</script>"; 

  }
```

Porque que não esta a somar tudo desse client_id????

Answer (score 3):

Você tem que dar teu alert depois do `while`

```
$exp_selector = "SELECT reward_qty FROM public_rewards WHERE client_id = '".$_SESSION['u_id']."'";     
$exp_query = $con->query($exp_selector);

$reward_exp = rand(10,25);  

#antes do while, definir sum_value com valor 0
$sum_value = 0;

while($exp_detail = $exp_query->fetch_array()) {

      $percentages = $exp_detail['reward_qty'];

      #aqui atualizamos o valor de sum_value somando o valor antigo + o novo recebido do banco de dados
      $sum_value = $sum_value + $percentages;     
}

#depois o que o while terminar, passará ao alert mostrando o valor final da variável sum_alert
echo "<script>alert('$sum_value');</script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que esteja usando PDO na consulta.

Como está passando um parâmetro na query recomendaria primeiramente que usasse sempre o PREPARE e não concatenar diretamente a variável na query pois isso abre uma brecha de segurança.

Sobre sua dúvida, eu faria a soma nativamente com SQL mesmo e não com o PHP pois não vi a necessidade de fazer isso pelo script que você mostrou.

Segue um exemplo que fiz com uma base que testei aqui:

```
<?php

$idCli = 0;

$con = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=teste", "root", "root");
$stmt = $con->prepare('select sum(valor) as total from conta where idCli = :idCli');
$stmt->bindParam(':idCli', $idCli);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

/*
array(1) {
  ["total"]=>
  string(2) "20"
}
*/

?>

<script>alert(<?php echo $row['total'] ?>);</script>
```